# Plone catalog rebuild: AttributeError portal_setup

Tags: plone

Since a few days, I get following Error, if I rebuild the portal_catalog

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
  Module Products.CMFPlone.CatalogTool, line 446, in manage_catalogRebuild
  Module plone.app.discussion.patches, line 47, in patchedClearFindAndRebuild
  Module OFS.FindSupport, line 239, in ZopeFindAndApply
  Module OFS.FindSupport, line 198, in ZopeFindAndApply
  Module Products.ZCatalog.Lazy, line 190, in __getitem__
  Module plone.folder.ordered, line 94, in <lambda>
  Module plone.folder.ordered, line 59, in _getOb
AttributeError: 'portal_setup'
```

Has anyone an Idea, what could be wrong?

Plone 4.3.4

Comment: oho... seems like your missing `portal_setup`?? Can you got to `http://yourplonesite/portal_setup/manage_main` with your browser?

Comment: Yes, portal_setup works, I can export profiles and take snapshots... This is the strange.... Also a simple catalog "update" works

Comment: You need to debug `plone.folder.ordered, line 94`. You need to knwo actual  object, on  which this problem occurs.

Comment: Taking a copy of the database to a dev system and narrowing down the critical objects by starting to delete folders (and undoing the delete if the problem goes away) might be easier if you don't feel comfortable patching distribution source files.

Comment: As you write that you encounter the error since a few days: Have there been made any changes lately,  like an upgrade, f.e.?

Comment: No, maybe the error occurred for quite some time, but I never do a complete rebuild...

Comment: It fails in following line https://github.com/plone/plone.folder/blob/1.0.8/src/plone/folder/ordered.py#L56 with id "portal_setup" which is present in ZMI, and it works - weird

Comment: Yeah, key-errors are caught and made to raise an attribute-error, huh. Honestly can't tell what's going on, but had an err with Plone-4.3.9 and plone.app.folder, solved by pinning the latter to vs 1.2, maybe that can help.

Comment: i use plone.folder = 1.0.8, which is the latest, pa.folder 1.2.0 or 1.1.2, nothing changed

Comment: plone.*app*.folder I ment, but it's probably unrelated. Maybe the triggering file `plone.app.discussion.patches` might be the cause, at least `patches.py` is not present in its recent releases anymore and and only needed for migrating old-style-comments to new-style, as I get it. A bug-report might be a better place to track this down.

Comment: In pa.discussion v2.2.18 patches.py is present, and its the same code like in. I think its something with pa.multilingual, I guess - I can't delete all LangaugeRootFolders (de/en), altough the work fine. Already tried with pa.multilingual versions 2.0.2 (2.0.1)

Comment: Update from plone.app.multilingual 2.0a3 -> plone.app.multilingual 2.0.1 breaks something in the catalog.... -> https://github.com/plone/plone.app.multilingual/issues/241

Answer (score 1):

The old language root folder implementation left garbage ids in the IOrdering of the folder. This needs a manual cleanup. An example here https://gist.github.com/jensens/356ab35614c4c0a7c626d8ba4a7a8479 - you may need to append values to the blacklist, depending on language and addons installed.